# Spring 24 v60.0 Changes in Iterable's Type Checking and Inference Mechanism Break Backward Compatibility

Tags: apex, polymorphism, parameterized-interface, type-checking, type-inference

Switching from `v59.0` to `v60.0` I noticed a significant change in handling type checking and inference with `Iterable<T>` types.

A very simple example:

```
new List<Id>() instanceof Iterable<String>;
```

**v59.0**

> `// true`

**v60.0**

> **Compile Failure:** `Operation instanceof is always true since an instance of List<Id> is always an instance of System.Iterable<String>`

Basically, starting from `v60.0` the `List<? extends T>` is always an instance of `Iterable<T>`.

the `Set<? extends T>` is also always an instance of `Iterable<T>` but starting from a few releases ago.

I'm not going to complain about the impact of breaking backward compatibility as well as the fact that these changes were missing in [**Salesforce Spring ’24 Release Notes**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex.htm&release=248&type=5)

**Questions:**

- What is the motivation behind these type-checking and inference changes?
- What are the following consequences?